# How to display current date in text format on textview in android using android.text.format?

Tags: android, java.util.date

I am getting result as 12/1/2012 but I want to display as "Saturday December 1,2012" my code is as below please give me a solution if you have......

```
Date date = new Date();
myDateString = DateFormat.getDateFormat(getApplicationContext()).format(date).toString();
dateTxt.setText(myDateString);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See this Example

```
 String[] formats = new String[] {
   "yyyy-MM-dd",
   "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm",
   "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mmZ",
   "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSZ",
   "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ",
 };
 for (String format : formats) {
   SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(format, Locale.US);
   System.err.format("%30s %s\n", format, sdf.format(new Date(0)));
   sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
   System.err.format("%30s %s\n", format, sdf.format(new Date(0)));
 }
```

Which produces this output when run in the PDT time zone:

```
                 yyyy-MM-dd 1969-12-31
                 yyyy-MM-dd 1970-01-01
           yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm 1969-12-31 16:00
           yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm 1970-01-01 00:00
          yyyy-MM-dd HH:mmZ 1969-12-31 16:00-0800
          yyyy-MM-dd HH:mmZ 1970-01-01 00:00+0000
   yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSZ 1969-12-31 16:00:00.000-0800
   yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSZ 1970-01-01 00:00:00.000+0000
 yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ 1969-12-31T16:00:00.000-0800
 yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ 1970-01-01T00:00:00.000+0000
```

So use this format:

```
"EEEE, MMMM dd, yyyy" -> "Monday, April 6, 1970"
```

See these references for complete detail

1. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateFormat.html
2. http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

   import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
   import java.util.Date;
   import java.util.Locale;

   String Format =  "EEEE, MMMM dd, yyyy";

   Date today = new Date();
   SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(Format, Locale.ENGLISH);
   System.err.format("%30s %s\n", Format, sdf.format(today));

This is printing `EEEE, MMMM dd, yyyy Saturday, December 01, 2012`

Check your imports and if problem persists Please try to post your new code.

Comment: I have modified my code accordingly but getting error as "getDateInstance is undefined for the type DateFormat"...

Comment: I have changed my code but it's giving result like "java.text.simpleDateFormat@.."

Comment: String Format =  "EEEE, MMMM dd, yyyy";

  Date today = new Date();
  SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(Format, Locale.ENGLISH);
  System.err.format("%30s %s\n", Format, sdf.format(today));
  dateTxt.setText(""+sdf.toString());

Comment: Just change this and you are done. dateTxt.setText(""+sdf.format(today));